# asp.net mvc executable scripts in textbox injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to know how to handle executable scripts in a textbox / ckeditor / any input control.

For example, if I enter:

```
<script>alert('hi')</script>
```

How should I handle this script in the textbox / ckeditor / input control?

Comment: Do you want to validate against this type of input - or - use the input and execute it on your page?

Comment: no i don't want to validate against the input just it must not be exected

Answer (score 1):

If you use Visual Studio 2010 you'd better create text box with HtmlHelper (Note using `<%:`):

```
<%: Html.TextBox("name") %>
```

it will prevent you from JavaScript injection.